# Autowiring a field in a Cucumber step produces NullPointerException

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, cucumber-jvm

Cucumber runner configuration :

```
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(features = "/features",glue {""})
@ContextConfiguration(classes = Init.class,
        initializers = ConfigFileApplicationContextInitializer.class)
public class Test {
}
```

Feature file :

```
class feature {
  Scenario: Save test in db.
    When I inject a payload in the aws queue
    Then it should be integrated in database
}
```

Step Definition file::

```
@CucumberAbstract
@ContextConfiguration("classpath:application.yml")
public class MyStepdefs {

    @Autowired
    private QueueMessagingTemplate queueMessagingTemplate;

    @Autowired
    TestRepository testRepository;

    String message = "Hi";

    public MyStepdefs() {
        When("^I inject a payload in the aws queue$", () -> {
            this.queueMessagingTemplate.convertAndSend("QUEUE_NAME", message);
        });
    }

    @Then("^it should be integrated in database$")
    public void itShouldBeIntegratedInDatabase() throws Throwable {
        //validations
    }
}
```

I tried creating a custom annotation here and using this annotation on top of stepDefinition file.
AbstractTest :::

```
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = Init.class, loader = 
                      SpringApplicationContextLoader.class)
@SpringBootTest
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
public @interface CucumberAbstract {
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Cucumber runner (`cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber`) doesn't load any Spring context.
So your cucumber step class is not Spring aware.
To inject a bean into a field of your class, you have to load the Spring context, in your case the Spring Boot context.

So specifying `@SpringBootTest` is what you are looking for :

```
@SpringBootTest
public class MyStepdefs {
  ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried adding @SpringBootTest but still it doesn't work. Also the application.yml file where i have defined all the properties are also not getting loaded. Is there something i am still missing ?

Comment: Do you see the Spring container start ?

Comment: Nope. It is not started

Comment: debugger directly comes to step definition file as soon as Test is run and logs says nothing but "Connected to the target VM, address: '*******', transport: 'socket'"

Comment: there are no logs stating that the spring container started. only error i get is null pointer exception since the autowired annotation is not working. Could you please help me out

Comment: Do you have to initialize the Spring container at all in your @Before methods? If Cucumber has control of the program flow (see Inversion of Control), maybe Spring needs to be explicitly looped in.

Comment: The @SpringBootTest annotation can be used when we need to bootstrap the entire container. The annotation works by creating the ApplicationContext. So the Spring container should start  with that. But it is not happening unfortunately :-(

Comment: Sorry for the trouble. I figured it out. I have two dependencies "cucumber-picocontainer" and "cucumber-spring" which is preventing my spring container to get started. But, now i am facing another issue like I have application.yml file in resource folder where i have defined 
spring:
  profiles: local
but, how can i load this in to my test cases ??

Comment: Please check my answer, it works and logs the Spring startup when running the CucumberRunner

Comment: I got ``.CucumberBackendException: Glue class class ulala.aop.integration.steps.HealCheckSteps and class ulala.aop.integration.steps.KafkaSteps both attempt to configure the spring context. Please ensure only one glue class configures the spring context``

Answer (score 1):

Actually what you need is to integrate Cucumber with Spring Boot.
So you need to add these dependencies for you maven project:

```
    <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
            <version>4.7.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.7.4</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-spring</artifactId>
            <version>4.7.4</version>
        </dependency>
```

Your cucumber runner is the same:

```
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(plugin = {"pretty"}, features = {"src/main/resources"})
public class ReportCaseCucumberTest {
}
```

Now in you StepDefinition class you need to configure the ContextConfiguration to be able to use Spring.

```
@SpringBootTest
@ContextConfiguration(
        classes = Application.class,
        loader = SpringBootContextLoader.class)
public class StepsDefinitions {

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext appContext;
}
```

Now in you StepDefinition class you can use "Autowired" annotation to inject beans.

This solved my problem, also you can check this tutorial:
https://medium.com/@bcarunmail/set-up-and-run-cucumber-tests-in-spring-boot-application-d0c149d26220

Comment: Thanks! Spend some good time trying to solve this riddle.Thanks man!